# Top 3 values in a CSV column in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file as below:

[image]

I want to print the top 3 customers (customer_id and order_id) that placed the most amount of orders.

I have tried the following:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    file = csv.reader(f)

    # sort based on customer id
    sorted_file = sorted(file, key=lambda d: d[1])
```

I am sure if this approach is correct. Also, I do not intend to use Pandas or Numpy for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `successful` and `waiting` both count as an order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of the `status` column is not a factor to choose the top 3 customers, you can create a dictionary with the number of orders.

**Code:**

```
import csv


with open("orders.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    orders_count = {}
    for line in reader:
        orders_count[line["customer_id"]] = orders_count.get(line["customer_id"], 0) + 1
    customers = sorted(orders_count.items(), key=lambda customer:customer[1], reverse=True)
    print(customers[:3])
```

**Output:**

```
[('10', 3), ('11', 3), ('13', 3)]
```

`orders.csv`:

```
order_id,customer_id,status
1,10,Successful
2,11,Successful
3,11,Successful
4,10,Waiting
5,12,Waiting
6,10,Successful
7,11,Wairing
8,13,Successful
9,13,Waiting
10,13,Successful
```

**Explanation:**

- Read the csv file content using `DictReader` method. Details can be found [in the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)
- Created a dictionary `orders_count` to count the number of orders of each customer. I assume each customer has a unique customer id.
- Sorted the `orders_count` by value to get the sorted list of customers by total number of orders. `reverse=True` used for descending sort.
- Finally, printed the top 3 customers with most number of orders.

Answer (score 0):

I think this soulf fix you problem

```
import csv

filee = open("test.csv", "r")
data = csv.reader(filee)

my_dict = {}
for i in data:

    temp = i[1]
    try:
        int(temp)
    except:
        continue

    try:
        my_dict[temp] += 1

    except:
        my_dict[temp] = 1

sorted_dict = dict(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0]))

a=0
for i in sorted_dict.keys():
    if a == 3:
        break
    print(i)
    a+=1
```